# How to write a phpunit test for a function that uses GDImage imagecreatefromstring

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, gd

I am writing a test for a service that creates an image using the GD library. Under normal operation, the method runs the following without issue:

```
imagecreatefromstring($this->imagick->getImageBlob());
```

When that line is hit during the unit test it errors with:

```
Error: Call to undefined function App\Services\imagecreatefromstring()
```

How do I let the unit test know where that method comes from?

sample test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Services;
use GDImage;

public function testReturnsError()
{
    // Arrange
    .. some arrangement


    Storage::shouldReceive('disk')
        ->with(self::SOURCE_DISK)
        ->andReturnSelf();

    Storage::shouldReceive('path')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn('123');

    // Act
    $image = $service->getImage('/path/here');

    // Assert
    ...some assertion
}
```

service function:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use GdImage;
class SomeService
{
public function getImage(string $filePath): GdImage
{
    try {
        $decryptedFile = $this->decryptFile(Storage::disk(self::SOURCE_DISK)->path($filePath));

        $this->imagick->readImageBlob($decryptedFile);
        $this->imagick->setImageFormat('png');

        return imagecreatefromstring($this->imagick->getImageBlob());
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
       
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Make sure that namespaces are used correctly in UnitTests. An attempt is made to find the function imagecreatefromstring() under App\Services\. In your test, write `\imagecreatefromstring()` or set the namespace correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To be clear the 'imagecreatefromstring' exists in the application code not the unit test itself. I meant that as the unit test runs, when it gets to that line it errors out.

Comment: The error means that yours is wrong with the namespace declaration and thus imagecreatefromstring() is resolved incorrectly. This can be in the test or in the application. I could speculate for a long time now. But it would be better if you show the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of namespaces looks good to me. So I exclude it as a namespace problem.

Now I assume that you are running the tests in your local development environment.

My guess is that you are running the tests on a different version of PHP to the one your application is running, and that the PHP CLI version does not have GD installed. This is a common mistake if you have installed PHP locally, rather than running it via Docker, and then run the tests in the PHP image.

Create an info.php and put it in the same directory as index.php. Then call your application with /phpinfo.php.

```php
<?PHP
phpinfo();
```

Then open a terminal or CLI on your local computer and execute the following command:

```bash
# Show version
php -v
```

If the PHP versions are not the same, then you need to update the PHP CLI to the PHP version of the application. I would at least recommend doing this.

If you use tools that install a LAMP environment, you can usually install multiple versions of PHP in parallel.

If both versions are the same, check which extensions PHP CLI contains.

```bash
# List auf modules
php -m
```

If you are still missing extensions like GD, you have to install or activate them for the PHP CLI version.